# Can't connect to Pgbouncer using psql

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgbouncer

I have created a docker container for PGbouncer.
(Docker image from - https://hub.docker.com/r/edoburu/pgbouncer)

```
docker run -d -it --name=pb -e DB_NAME=events -e DB_HOST=localhost -e DB_USER=postgres -e DB_PASSWORD=postgres  -e LISTEN_ADDR=127.0.0.1 -e LISTEN_PORT=8083 -e AUTH_TYPE=any -e AUTH_FILE=/Users/nandeeshnaik/Desktop/pg/userlist.txt brainsam/pgbouncer:latest
```

the above command runs the pgbouncer. 
Logs from the docker container,

```
adduser: user 'postgres' in use
#pgbouncer.ini
# Description
# Config file is in “ini” format. Section names are between “[” and “]”.
# Lines starting with “;” or “#” are taken as comments and ignored.
# The characters “;” and “#” are not recognized when they appear later in the line.
[databases]
* = host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres

[pgbouncer]
# Generic settings
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
listen_port = 8083
auth_file = /Users/nandeeshnaik/Desktop/pg/userlist.txt
auth_type = any
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits

# Log settings
admin_users = postgres

# Connection sanity checks, timeouts

# TLS settings

# Dangerous timeouts
################## end file ##################
Starting pgbouncer...
2019-09-15 20:05:23.309 1 LOG File descriptor limit: 1048576 (H:1048576), max_client_conn: 100, max fds possible: 110
2019-09-15 20:05:23.309 1 LOG listening on 127.0.0.1:8083
2019-09-15 20:05:23.309 1 LOG listening on unix:/tmp/.s.PGSQL.8083
2019-09-15 20:05:23.309 1 LOG process up: pgbouncer 1.8.1, libevent 2.1.8-stable (epoll), adns: c-ares 1.13.0, tls: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

After this i'm trying to connect to pgbouncer using postgres client (PSQL).

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8083 -U postgres events
```

I get the following error..

```
(base) MUMCAP0120:pg nandeeshnaik$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8083 -U postgres events
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 8083?
```

- using Mac
- locally installed Postgresql.
- userlist.txt has only **"postgres"**, both username and passwords are in pain text.

Any suggestions and solution to resolve the issue is much appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any more clarity.

Answer (score -1):

You missed port mapping flag to `docker run` command, so it should be `docker run -p 8083:8083 ...`:

```
docker run -d -p 8083:8083 -it --name=pb -e DB_NAME=events -e DB_HOST=localhost -e DB_USER=postgres -e DB_PASSWORD=postgres  -e LISTEN_ADDR=127.0.0.1 -e LISTEN_PORT=8083 -e AUTH_TYPE=any -e AUTH_FILE=/Users/nandeeshnaik/Desktop/pg/userlist.txt brainsam/pgbouncer:latest
```

Comment: No luck even after adding "-p 8083:8083".  Same error.